# best way to deal with a large number of objects in python

Tags: python

What is the best approach to deal with a larger number of instances of the same class. Currently, I add them to a list and then loop through the list if I need to do call a method.

```
[o.method() for o in myObjects]
```

Is there a way to deal with them as a collection in the sense that the above could be replaced with something like

```
myObjects.method()
```

I though of having a metaClass instead of that list that contains the list and does this, but I wonder if that is getting a bit to convoluted. Is there a preferred way to do this?

Edit:
I generally wont need the return values

Comment: Did you want to have the *return values* of those method calls? Or is the rv discarded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have the return value of all those method calls in a list, then using either `map()` or a list comprehension is the correct way of processing a sequence of homogeneous objects:

```
from operator import methodcaller
results = map(methodcaller('method'), myObjects)
```

In Python 3, `map()` returns a generator instead and to produce a list it's most efficient to just use a list comprehension:

```
results = [o.method() for o in myObjects()]
```

However, if all you are interested in is the method call itself and you are discarding the return value (because it's `None`, for example), then you are now creating a list object for nothing. You are using the list comprehension for a side-effect and needlessly producing a large list of `None` references in the process.

In such a case, you just use a simple `for` loop:

```
for o in myObjects:
    o.method()
```

Because of Python's dynamic nature, there is no way for Python to know if a sequence of objects all have the same method, in any case. Because the Zen of Python states that explicit is better than implicit, and readability counts, there is no 'collection call' syntax; you are expected to spell this out explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

However you write it, the only way to run `method` on every object is by looping over them (Unless you can rewrite `method` and optimise it for a list).  E.g., if you have some class method or collection method called `myObjects.method`, internally it would still have some variation of

```
for o in myObjects:
    o.method()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also sub-class `list` in order to handle this case:

```
class customList(list):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            return super(customList, self).__getattribute__(attr)
        except AttributeError:
            method_list = [getattr(el, attr) for el in self]
            def call_me(*args, **kwargs):
                return [method(*args, **kwargs) for method in method_list]
            return call_me
```

Here is a test class:

```
class Test:
    _instances = customList()

    def __init__(self, arg=0):
        self._instances.append(self)
        self.nb = arg

    def incr(self, arg):
        self.nb += arg

    def get_nb(self):
        return self.nb

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls):
        return cls._instances
```

And this is what you get:

```
>>> a = Test(0)
>>> b = Test(1)
>>> c = Test(2)
>>> instances = Test.get_instances()
>>> instances.incr(3)
[None, None, None]
>>> instances.get_nb()
[3, 4, 5]
```